# Creating TCP Connections with Node.js in C++

Tags: c++, node.js

I getting ready to write a small client module for Node.js using C++. The client will communicate with a remote server. I started by creating a class that communicates with the remote server, and I will eventually wrap that class with the main module class which inherits from node::ObjectWrap.

Typically I would use the Boost library for networking, but it dawns on me that Node has a lot of networking stuff built into it. Since I'm linking against Node anyway, I figure I could save myself a few dependencies by using Node's built in networking, but I can't find any documentation on Node's networking within C++.

Can anyone provide an example of using Node to create TCP connections, and send/receive data over the connection, from within C++? Or at least link to some documentation on the subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node.js C++ interface is being rewritten for 0.6

Any 0.4 C++ code will break. This put's your in a painful place to do this C++ interface stuff. Basically the node.js team has written [libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/) that is their networking library which is an abstraction on libev & IOCP.

The best "learning" resource you can find is the [libuv unit tests](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/tree/master/test). You will need to test this with the latest version of 0.5.x or maybe even the master branch from the node project.

You may want to check out the [tcp writealot](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/blob/master/test/test-tcp-writealot.c) test.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. I'm writing a Node module in C++ for the learning experience, so the up coming API change isn't a *huge* deal for me.

Comment: @mellowsoon I would recommend you a) check those tests work, and be go ask the guys in #node on freenode that using libuv is sensible.